# DashInsert Coderbyte Challenge - Why does arr[i]%2===1 work?

Tags: javascript

The Coderbyte problem is: 
*Using the JavaScript language, have the function DashInsert(str) insert dashes ('-') between each two odd numbers in str. For example: if str is 454793 the output should be 4547-9-3. Don't count zero as an odd number.*

So when the input is 99946, the output should be 9-9-946.

I had this solution, which wouldn't quite work:

```
function DashInsert(num) {
var arr = num.toString().split('');
var i = 0;
while(i < arr.length-1){
if( arr[i]%2 !==0 && arr[i+1]%2 !==0){ 
arr.splice(i+1,0,'-'); 
}
i++
}
return arr.join(''); 
}
```

Then I found this similar answer:

```
function DashInsert(num) {
var arr = num.toString().split('');

var i = 0

while(i < arr.length-1){
if( arr[i]%2===1 && arr[i+1]%2===1){ 
arr.splice(i+1,0,'-'); 
}
i++
}

return arr.join(''); }
str = 99946;
alert(DashInsert(str));
```

Can anyone explain why it should be arr[i]%2===1?

Comment: There are two possible values for `n % 2` when `n` is an integer ...

Answer (score 0):

both are correct .
for example , take 9 : 9%2 != 0 and also 9%2 ==1 . think about it , all odd numbers can be split to
2n+1 . a modulo of 2 will always return 1 , which is not 0.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who stumbles upon this in a frustrated googling haze...

After the first hyphen is added, it changes the length of the array, so it gets evaluated in the loop to see if the hyphen element !== 0.

Since a '-' !== 0, another hyphen is added.

This is also why you keep blowing your stack since the hyphen keeps changing the length of your array (side note, always cache your length in a variable outside of your for loop and use that in your loop instead).

To fix it, you could add a bunch more &&'s to your if statement i.e.

if(theArray[x] % 2 !== 0  && theArray[x+1]% 2 !== 0 && theArray[x] !== '-' && theArray[x+1] !== '-')

or you could just be more specific and only look for modulo results that evaluate to 1.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it works..

HTH..

private static String createDashedString(String str) {

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    char[] chararray = str.toCharArray();

    for (int i=0;i<chararray.length-1;i++) {

        int firstInt = Character.getNumericValue(chararray[i]);
        int nextInt = Character.getNumericValue(chararray[i+1]);
        if ((firstInt%2 !=0) && (nextInt%2 !=0)) {
            builder.append(firstInt);
            builder.append("-");
        }else {
            builder.append(firstInt);
        }
    }
    builder.append(chararray[chararray.length-1]);
    return builder.toString();

}


public static void main(String args[]) {

    String str = "999999";
                  //01234
    System.out.println(createDashedString(str));


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function DashInsert(str) { 

    let bil = 0;
     while (bil < str.length-1) {
         if (Number(str[bil]) % 2 === 1 && Number(str[bil+1]) % 2 === 1) {
           str = str.slice(0,bil+1) + "-" + str.slice(bil+1);
           bil = bil + 2;
         }
         else {  
             bil++;
         }
   }
   return str;  
          
 }

 console.log(DashInsert("454793"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let x = '99946' 
    let z=[]
    for(var i = 0;i<x.length;i++){
      if(x[i]%2 == 0 && x[i+1]%2 == 1 ){
        z+=x[ i ]
      }else if (x[i]%2 == 1 && x[i+1]%2 == 0){
          z+=x[i]
      }else if (x[i]%2 == 1 && x[i+1]%2 == 1){
           z+=x[i]+"-"
      }else{
          z+=x[i]
      }
     }
    console.log(z)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Do not post an answer with merely codes. While your solution can be useful, you should also explain why the code will fix the problem that was described in the question